# Cuckoo failed in an unhandled exception

Tags: python

I installed Cuckoo with all the dependencies required, but when I try to run the `cuckoo` command to start it, it throws this error:

```
$ cuckoo

   __   _  _   __   _   _   __   __
  /__/\ //\//\ /_/\ /_/\//\ /_/\ /__/\
  \:::_\/ \:\ \:\ \\:::\/ \::.\ \\ \ \\::: \ \\:::_ \ \
   \:\ \  _\:\ \:\ \\:\ \  _\:: \/_) \ \\:\ \ \ \\:\ \ \ \
    \:\ \//\\:\ \:\ \\:\ \//\\:. __  ( ( \:\ \ \ \\:\ \ \ \
     \:\_\ \ \\:\_\:\ \\:\_\ \ \\: \ )  \ \ \:\_\ \ \\:\_\ \ \
      \__\/ \_\/ \_\/ \\/\\/  \_\/ \__\/

 Cuckoo Sandbox 2.0.7
 www.cuckoosandbox.org
 Copyright (c) 2010-2018

 Checking for updates...
Oops! Cuckoo failed in an unhandled exception!
Sometimes bugs are already fixed in the development release, it is therefore recommended to retry with the latest development release available https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo
If the error persists please open a new issue at https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/issues

=== Exception details ===
Cuckoo version: 2.0.7
OS version: posix
OS release: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
Python version: 2.7.17
Python implementation: CPython
Machine arch: x86_64
Modules: alembic:1.0.10 androguard:3.0.1 argparse:1.2.1 asn1crypto:0.24.0 attrs:20.3.0 beautifulsoup4:4.5.3 capstone:3.0.5rc2 chardet:2.3.0 click:6.6 colorama:0.3.7 configparser:4.0.2 contextlib2:0.6.0.post1 cryptography:2.1.4 cuckoo:2.0.7 django-extensions:1.6.7 django:1.8.4 dnspython:1.15.0 dpkt:1.8.7 ecdsa:0.16.1 egghatch:0.2.3 elasticsearch:5.3.0 enum34:1.1.6 flask-sqlalchemy:2.4.0 flask:0.12.2 functools32:3.2.3.post2 future:0.18.2 gevent:1.2.2 greenlet:1.0.0 httpreplay:0.2.6 idna:2.6 importlib-metadata:2.1.1 ipaddress:1.0.23 itsdangerous:1.1.0 jinja2:2.9.6 jsbeautifier:1.6.2 jsonschema:3.2.0 keyring:10.6.0 keyrings.alt:3.0 mako:1.1.4 markupsafe:1.1.1 olefile:0.43 oletools:0.51 pathlib2:2.3.5 peepdf:0.4.2 pefile2:1.2.11 pillow:3.2.0 pip:9.0.3 pycrypto:2.6.1 pyelftools:0.24 pygobject:3.26.1 pyguacamole:0.6 pymisp:2.4.106 pymongo:3.0.3 pyopenssl:20.0.1 pyrsistent:0.16.1 python-dateutil:2.4.2 python-editor:1.0.4 python-magic:0.4.12 python:2.7.17 pythonaes:1.0 pyxdg:0.25 requests:2.13.0 roach:0.1.2 scandir:1.10.0 scapy:2.3.2 secretstorage:2.3.1 setuptools:44.1.1 sflock:0.3.10 six:1.11.0 sqlalchemy:1.3.3 tlslite-ng:0.6.0 unicorn:1.0.1 urllib3:1.26.3 vboxapi:1.0 virtualenv:15.1.0 wakeonlan:0.2.2 werkzeug:1.0.1 wheel:0.30.0 wsgiref:0.1.2 yara-python:3.6.3 zipp:1.2.0

2021-03-15 08:23:28,106 [cuckoo] ERROR: AttributeError: _exit_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/main.py", line 297, in main
    cuckoo_init(level, ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/main.py", line 170, in cuckoo_init
    check_version(ctx.ignore_vuln)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cuckoo/core/startup.py", line 113, in check_version
    params={"version": version}, timeout=6
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1099, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1139, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1095, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 898, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 874, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 311, in sendall
    sent = self._send_until_done(data[total_sent:total_sent + SSL_WRITE_BLOCKSIZE])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 301, in _send_until_done
    return self.connection.send(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1644, in send
    with _from_buffer(buf) as data:
AttributeError: _exit_
```

Note that `cuckoo web runserver` is working fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is a bug in the program.  You will need to file a bug with the upstream cuckoomaintainers.

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely a bug in Cuckoo.

Per the message:

> Sometimes bugs are already fixed in the development release, it is therefore recommended to retry with the latest development release available https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo
>
> If the error persists please open a new issue at https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/issues

Since this wasn't installed from the repositories, you will need to follow the message's guidelines, and test the latest devel release available, and if the issue then persists, file an issue as the message states, as this would be a Bug in the program itself.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But i have one more question if you don't mind, after downloading the folder from  https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo i replaced the older one in /dist-packages, this is giving me a configuration error how can i fix it?

Comment: That I can't help with.  You might need to blast the config it tries initially and reconfigure it.